# No entiendo muy bien esta sentencia que tiene callback en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Resulta que aprendiendo javascript me tope con esta sentencia que no la entiendo muy bien, que tiene callback. Devuelve numero menor a mayor, pero no entiendo bien la sintaxis. No entiendo la sintaxis `((a,b)=> a-b ))`

```
const numbers = [1,100,3,333,20]
console.log(numbers.sort((a,b)=> a -b ))
```

Comment: ¿No entiendes la sintaxis? ¿O no entiendes lo que hace el código?

Answer (score 3):

*Entiendo que la duda que posees es respecto a las funciones de flecha o funciones lambda.*

> (a,b)=> a - b)

*Expresado en la forma tradicional*

```
function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

*Te comparto la función de la forma tradicional para que puedas comprender mejor el comportamiento de dicha función. El como esto influye en la función sort, ya viene siendo un análisis basicamente a la funcion sort y sus especificaciones.*

[Documentación de la función sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

*Te comparto ruta donde puedes revisar la documentación relacionada a este tipo de sentencias, de igual forma, entenderás el comportamiento de la función que se pasa como parámetro a la función sort.*

[Documentación funciones de flecha o funciones lambda](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

*Espero te sirva, saludos.*